# commandline.txt for GTA 4 doesn't work on Steam

Tags: steam, windows-7, grand-theft-auto-iv

I have GTA 4 on Steam and I use commandline.txt but it doesn't work. When I launch it, Rockstar Social Club just pops up asking me to log in and after I click Play or Play Offline, the game starts and commandline.txt doesn't work just as if it's ignored

I've tried:

- Running without Steam (Desktop shortcut to LaunchGTAIV.exe)
- Arranging the options so that they're all on one line
- Arranging the options so that each option is on one line
- It's updated (1.0.7.0) 'cause Steam updates it

Also, I didn't make any spelling mistakes 'cause none of the options worked

My commandline.txt

```
-noprecache
-minspecaudio
-norestrictions
-nomemrestrict
-framelimit
-percentvidmem 100
```

*Steam launch options doesn't seem to work either*

**Never mind. Steam launch options are working again.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steam has built-in support for letting you specify command-line args for games.

Right-click the game's entry in the Library and click Properties. On the window that pops up, there's a button named "Set Launch Options...", and clicking that gives you a textbox that lets you type in command-line arguments that Steam will use when launching your game.

You can include the entries you would've had in commandline.txt in there (all on one line, of course, since the textbox in Steam is one line only).

Comment: Yes I know that but Steam launch options doesn't seem to be working either. I'll try that again to make sure