# In-game settings cannot be modified

Tags: grand-theft-auto-iv

The in-game settings in GTA IV are stuck at the minimal. (Resource use is 202MB.) But my computer runs a 4 GB ATI GPU.

So, I tried the Commandline.txt method, however this didn't affect the game in any way. I then tried to add the command lines to a shortcut, still nothing changed.

I have never had this problem happen before. The command line has always worked.

Any ideas on how to get it to realise I have 4 GB usable?

Answer (score 1):

GTA IV allows to override some of the default settings of the engine by creating a file called "commandline.txt" in the root of the game folder (e.g. Steam/SteamApps/common/GTA IV/).

These are the options available:

```
-renderquality: Set the render quality of the game. (0-4)
-shadowdensity: Set the shadow density of the game. (0-16)
-texturequality:    Set the texture quality of the game. (0-2)
-viewdistance:  Set the view distance of the game (0-99)
-detailquality: Set the detail quality of the game. (0-99)
-novblank:  Disable wait for vblank (No Vsync)
-norestrictions:    Do not limit graphics settings
-width: Set width of main render window (default is 800)
-height:    Set height of main render window (default is 600)
-safemode:  Run the graphics in the lowest setting possible
-frameLimit:    Limit frame to interval of refresh rate 
(ex If refreshrate is 60HZ –frameLimit 1 = Locks down to 60HZ)
-refreshrate:   Set the refresh rate of main render window 
– Warning - Monitor must support (ex. –refreshrate 60) 
-fullscreen:    Force fullscreen mode
-windowed:  Force windowed mode
-availablevidmem: Set amount of physical Video Memory(ex. –availablevidmem 0.9)
-percentvidmem: Percentage of video memory to make available to GTA
```

I would first try to add only

```
-norestrictions
```

to the file and see if that solves the problem. If not, add

```
-availablevidmem 4098
```

That should definitely solve it. In case you have the Game on Steam and it ignores the file, use this answer to add the commands to the launch options of Steam:

[commandline.txt for GTA 4 doesn't work on Steam](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27837/commandline-txt-for-gta-4-doesnt-work-on-steam?rq=1)